# What statagy to adopt for building html5 pages?

Tags: html

Features of HTML5 are no doubt very compelling but is it a good time to start development in HTML5 ?

I just have started development in HTML5 and realized at the time even not all HTML5 input types are supported by all browsers. It means it is not sure about basic stuff like input forms.

Please share how you are managing these things ? (Using HTML5 code with browsers currently supporting HTML5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum behind HTML5 is strong and it is indeed a good time to get started if you have not already.

At the lowest level, you would need to write feature detection in your pages to see if the particular browser supports the HTML5 feature that you want to use.

I suggest the following:

- Use sites like [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) to determine the current support for a particular feature across browsers.
- Use templates like [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), which give you a structure for the HTML5 page that you can use , with support for various shims that bring in support for HTML5 features in older browsers.
- If you prefer doing the detection yourself, use a library like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com).

Answer (score 3):

HTML 5 is still under development so you've got to be careful. Certain features, such as the more basic ones like `<header>` and `<footer>`, are less likely to change before the final release. The doctype decleration is unlikely to change. I wouldn't rely on the multimedia support as supported formats vary widely accross browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the table in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29). There is a lot of variability amongst browsers as to which parts of HTML5 are currently supported. [This website](https://html5test.com/) tests your web browser to see which features it supports, so install a bunch of different browsers on your computer and test them for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As with all cross-browser development, you can never rely on any support in the browser. If you target older browsers, then do not rely on HTML5 features. I haven't had problems with using the HTML5 *doctype* in older browsers, but specific features can be troublesome — e.g. you can use `<header>` elements, but IE won't let you style them in any way as it disregards `header` styles as invalid.

As long as you need to support old enough browsers, it will never be a good time to start using HTML5. The only thing that decides whether it's okay to use HTML5 is which browsers you want to support.

Comment: thanks. I am not referring old browsers. I am saying about IE9 and almost other current versions. Even these versions suppor different input types. I am doing some development where I don't need to target IE7,8 etc. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is much easier then previous ones, It has developed allot in input fields, though its still under development and not complete yet.

You can check here http://html5test.com/ which browser supports HTML5 how much?
Currently, Chrome is the best that supports the HTML5 more than any other web browser.

-Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Waleed. Please advice about statagy as well. I have checked html5test but what about how to use it. I mean not use it. Use it or certain features to use.

Comment: Actually there is no specific strategy about how to use HTML5.
Firstly remove the thinking about versions. Just type the code and let it work. Don't see that it is from HTML4 or HTML5, Just use it as you want it.

Comment: This site will help you about HTML5
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/ very well.
All of the tags,elements,syntax and other stuff are there for guidance.Use the search box when ever you want to search about it.